# Explanation of Oracle PARTITION BY vs GROUP BY for similar results

Tags: oracle, database-performance, query-performance

I have the following table (Marks):

```
firstname    lastname    Mark    
------------------------------
arun         prasanth    40      
ann          antony      45      
sruthy       abc         41      
new          abc         47      
arun         prasanth    45      
arun         prasanth    49      
ann          antony      49
```

And would like to add a column that tags if a record with specific columns occurs more than once. This is the result:

```
firstname    lastname    Mark    MULTI_FLAG
----------------------------------------------
arun         prasanth    40      1
ann          antony      45      1
sruthy       abc         41      0
new          abc         47      0
arun         prasanth    45      1
arun         prasanth    49      1
ann          antony      49      1
```

I can get the result with the following **GROUP BY** query:

```
SELECT M1.firstname
      ,M1.lastname
      ,M1.Mark
      ,M2.MULTI_COUNT
FROM Marks  M1
JOIN (SELECT firstname, lastname, CASE WHEN COUNT (*) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MULTI_COUNT
    FROM Marks
    GROUP BY firstname, lastname) M2
   ON M2.firstname = M1.firstname AND M2.lastname = M1.lastname;
```

Or by this much prettier **PARTITION BY** query:

```
SELECT
  firstname,
  lastname,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY
     firstname,
     lastname) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MULTI_FLAG
FROM
  Marks
```

Running the **GROUP BY** query on a similar large table returned in:
***34 m 56 s 595 ms***

Running the **PARTITION BY** query on a similar large table returned in:

1. First run: ***55 m 47 s 851 ms***
2. Second run: ***36 m 46 s 95 ms***

I would be interested in knowing:

1. The best way to achieve my results
2. What accounts for the performance difference.
3. EDIT: How to read the query plan.

EDIT:
**Oracle Version** 
    Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
    PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
    "CORE   11.2.0.3.0  Production"
    TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
    NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production

**PARTITION BY Plan**

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
Plan hash value: 3822227444

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                            |   668K|    90M|       | 90429   (1)| 00:18:06 |
|   1 |  WINDOW SORT                   |                            |   668K|    90M|    98M| 90429   (1)| 00:18:06 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER        |                            |   668K|    90M|       | 69340   (1)| 00:13:53 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL           | COUNTRY_REGION_MAPPINGS    |   177 |  4779 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    NESTED LOOPS                |                            |       |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |     NESTED LOOPS               |                            |   377K|    41M|       | 69335   (1)| 00:13:53 |
|   6 |      MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL      | PROJINFO_MAX_ITER_MVW      | 17713 |   328K|       |   782   (1)| 00:00:10 |
|*  7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | Q_CLIN_ASSUM_BYCOUN_PK     |     1 |       |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| Q_CLINICAL_ASSUM_BYCOUNTRY |    21 |  2016 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access(UPPER("CRM"."COUNTRY"(+))=UPPER("QCAB"."TRIAL_COUNTRY"))
   7 - access("PMIM"."OPPORTUNITYNUM"="QCAB"."OPPORTUNITYNUM" AND "PMIM"."CONTRACTNUM"="QCAB"."CONTRACTNUM" 
              AND "PMIM"."ITERATION"="QCAB"."ITERATION")
       filter(UPPER("QCAB"."SHEET_LOC") LIKE '%COUNTRY ASSUMPTIONS%' OR UPPER("QCAB"."SHEET_LOC") LIKE 
              'INPUT%')
```

**GROUP BY Plan**

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
Plan hash value: 648231064

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                            |   912 |  2052K|       |   226K  (1)| 00:45:22 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN                        |                            |   912 |  2052K|       |   226K  (1)| 00:45:22 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL               | COUNTRY_REGION_MAPPINGS    |   177 |  4779 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   HASH JOIN                       |                            | 89667 |   194M|    45M|   226K  (1)| 00:45:22 |
|   4 |    NESTED LOOPS                   |                            |       |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |     NESTED LOOPS                  |                            |   377K|    41M|       | 69335   (1)| 00:13:53 |
|   6 |      MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL         | PROJINFO_MAX_ITER_MVW      | 17713 |   328K|       |   782   (1)| 00:00:10 |
|*  7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN             | Q_CLIN_ASSUM_BYCOUN_PK     |     1 |       |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | Q_CLINICAL_ASSUM_BYCOUNTRY |    21 |  2016 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |    VIEW                           |                            |   668K|  1377M|       | 86518   (1)| 00:17:19 |
|  10 |     HASH GROUP BY                 |                            |   668K|    72M|    80M| 86518   (1)| 00:17:19 |
|* 11 |      HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER        |                            |   668K|    72M|       | 69340   (1)| 00:13:53 |
|  12 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL           | COUNTRY_REGION_MAPPINGS    |   177 |  2478 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |       NESTED LOOPS                |                            |       |       |       |            |          |
|  14 |        NESTED LOOPS               |                            |   377K|    35M|       | 69335   (1)| 00:13:53 |
|  15 |         MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL      | PROJINFO_MAX_ITER_MVW      | 17713 |   328K|       |   782   (1)| 00:00:10 |
|* 16 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN          | Q_CLIN_ASSUM_BYCOUN_PK     |     1 |       |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  17 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| Q_CLINICAL_ASSUM_BYCOUNTRY |    21 |  1701 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("R2"."TRIAL_COUNTRY_CD"="CRM"."COUNTRY_CD" AND 
              UPPER("CRM"."COUNTRY")=UPPER("QCAB"."TRIAL_COUNTRY"))
   3 - access("R2"."OPPORTUNITYNUM"="QCAB"."OPPORTUNITYNUM" AND "R2"."ITERATION"="QCAB"."ITERATION" AND 
              "R2"."CONTRACTNUM"="QCAB"."CONTRACTNUM" AND "R2"."ASSUMPTION"="QCAB"."ASSUMPTION")
   7 - access("PMIM"."OPPORTUNITYNUM"="QCAB"."OPPORTUNITYNUM" AND "PMIM"."CONTRACTNUM"="QCAB"."CONTRACTNUM" AND 
              "PMIM"."ITERATION"="QCAB"."ITERATION")
       filter(UPPER("QCAB"."SHEET_LOC") LIKE '%COUNTRY ASSUMPTIONS%' OR UPPER("QCAB"."SHEET_LOC") LIKE 'INPUT%')
  11 - access(UPPER("CRM"."COUNTRY"(+))=UPPER("QCAB"."TRIAL_COUNTRY"))
  16 - access("PMIM"."OPPORTUNITYNUM"="QCAB"."OPPORTUNITYNUM" AND "PMIM"."CONTRACTNUM"="QCAB"."CONTRACTNUM" AND 
              "PMIM"."ITERATION"="QCAB"."ITERATION")
       filter(UPPER("QCAB"."SHEET_LOC") LIKE '%COUNTRY ASSUMPTIONS%' OR UPPER("QCAB"."SHEET_LOC") LIKE 'INPUT%')
```

Comment: The execution plans might be interesting. Also how many rows are in the table, and which version of Oracle are you using? And did you run them in that order, and are those timings repeatable? (Just wondering if data caching might be having an effect.)

Comment: You probably need a SQL Monitor report to determine actual cardinalities and where time is being spent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you start with the analytic function `count(*)` which leads to a compact SQL.

The drawback of this aproach is that the data must be sorted (see `WINDOW SORT` operation). The `GROUP BY` approach avoids
the sorting as `HASH GROUP BY` may be used, which can lead to a better performance.

Your example is a bit more involved, as you do not use table but a view that joins three tables - this join is performed twice, for the `GROUP BY` and for the detail data; which
is of course not optimal.

So I'll start with the analytic function version of the query (possible with a `PARALLEL`option).

If you want to try the `GROUP BY` a lightway version is possible:

1) group only the duplicated keys

2) make `OUTER JOIN` to assign the `MULTI_FLAG`

example with execution plan below - simple test with your data

```
with dups as (
select firstname,lastname  from tmp
group by firstname,lastname
having count(*) > 1)
select tmp.FIRSTNAME, tmp.LASTNAME, tmp.MARK,
case when dups.firstname is not NULL then 1 else 0 end as MULTI_FLAG
from tmp
left outer join dups on tmp.firstname = dups.firstname and tmp.lastname = dups.lastname;
```

You still need to access your view twice, but the final join will be faster (espetially if you have only small number of duplicated keys).

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |      |   105K|    26M|       |  1673   (1)| 00:00:21 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER|      |   105K|    26M|    11M|  1673   (1)| 00:00:21 |
|   2 |   VIEW                |      |   105K|    10M|       |   128   (4)| 00:00:02 |
|*  3 |    FILTER             |      |       |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     HASH GROUP BY     |      |   105K|    10M|       |   128   (4)| 00:00:02 |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| TMP  |   105K|    10M|       |   125   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|   6 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL   | TMP  |   105K|    15M|       |   125   (1)| 00:00:02 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```